# "OSError: cannot open resource" using PIL

Tags: python, tkinter, import

I'm writing a program to add a watermark and it works, but when I try to change the font size, I constantly encounter errors

I tried to change the font, set it by default, but I don't always get an error

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfile
from PIL import Image, ImageTk, ImageDraw, ImageFont
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("600x500")
window.title('Upload your image')
open_file_path = None



label = tk.Label(window,text='Add Photo',width=30)
label.grid(row=0,column=0)
label.place(relx=0.25, rely=0.01)
button = tk.Button(window, text='Upload File', width=20,command = lambda:upload_file())
button.grid(row=1,column=0)
button.place(relx=0.29, rely=0.1)
text = tk.Text(width = 40,height = 5)
text.place(relx = 0.24, rely = 0.3)
button_confirm = tk.Button(window,text = "Confirm text watermark",command = lambda:retrieve_input())
button_confirm.place(relx = 0.33,rely = 0.5)

def retrieve_input():
   input_value = text.get('1.0','end-1c')
   return input_value
def upload_file():
   global open_file_path
   font_type = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf", 18)
   input_text = retrieve_input()
   open_file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
   image = Image.open(open_file_path)
   width,height = image.size
   draw_watermark = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
   fill_color = (203, 201, 201)
   x = width/2-50
   y = height/2-50
   position = (x,y)
   draw_watermark.text(xy=position, text=input_text, fill=fill_color, font=font_type)
   image.save('watermark_image.jpg')
   # plt.imshow(image)

window.mainloop()
```

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1948, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/admin/Desktop/Python/watermark_gui/main.py", line 17, in <lambda>
    button = tk.Button(window, text='Upload File', width=20,command = lambda:upload_file())
                                                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/admin/Desktop/Python/watermark_gui/main.py", line 30, in upload_file
    font_type = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf", 18)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/admin/Desktop/Python/watermark_gui/env/lib/python3.12/site-packages/PIL/ImageFont.py", line 797, in truetype
    return freetype(font)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/admin/Desktop/Python/watermark_gui/env/lib/python3.12/site-packages/PIL/ImageFont.py", line 794, in freetype
    return FreeTypeFont(font, size, index, encoding, layout_engine)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/admin/Desktop/Python/watermark_gui/env/lib/python3.12/site-packages/PIL/ImageFont.py", line 226, in __init__
    self.font = core.getfont(
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
OSError: cannot open resource
```

Comment: `command = lambda:upload_file()` I think you're not supposed to have the parentheses here.

Comment: I don't know what system you are on, but apparently 'arial.ttf' does not exist or you are using the wrong encoding. Try [this](https://github.com/OneMadGypsy/SimPIL-Font)

Comment: @JohnGordon: if you use `lambda` then you must have the parenthesis. However, in this case `lambda` is not necessary, in which case you would omit the parenthesis (eg: `command=upload_file`)

Comment: You're on MacOS.  There's no guarantee that "arial.ttf" exists.  If you do have a copy, pass the whole path to ImageFont.